# date.getTime is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am trying to compare some dates in javascript/jquery. But I am getting some error. What I did wrong here?

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
   console.log(date.getTime())
}
```

//here am geting date.getTime is not a function

Here is my function:

```
 $scope.myFunction =function(balance){
    $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: balance.defaultDate,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,           
        events: [
            {
                title: balance.title,
                start: balance.startDate                
            }
        ],

         dayRender: function (date, cell) {  // This is the callback function to modify a particular date cell.
            console.log(date.getDate());   //undefined
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the dayRender function. are you passing a date type object to it as the first argument.

Comment: what are you passing into those functions as the first argument? just because the argument is called date doesnt' mean it'll have date functions

Comment: It seems like date.getTime isn't a function! Seriously though, Without knowing what `date` is before it's passed to the function...any answer that someone gives you will just be a guess.

Comment: please check updated code.

Comment: The definition of `date` is still missing. Maybe `date` was created by `new Date`, instead of `new Date()` ..?

Comment: Log `date` instead of `date.getTime()` and tell us what the output is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getDate());
```

Instead of passing date object everytime you call `dayRender()`, you can use date directly in that function.

```
dayRender: function (cell) {
  var date = new Date();
  console.log(date.getTime());
  console.log(date.getDate());
  console.log(date.getYear());
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the `$scope.myFunction()`. here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/18168/) I have created with your code and it is working fine. the date you are receiving in in `dayRender()` is already a date type object. hence this might be some error in your code I have edited the code in your question copy that and try to run again.

Comment: so you want your calendar to show after you have clicked on grids?

Comment: i did what you are trying to do in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleJS/ADukg/15828/). works fine here.... are you sure  `dayRender()` is inside `.fullCalendar()` call?

Comment: How `date.getDate()` is directly working in fiddle but for me its showing `date.getDate() is not a function`

Comment: I have updated the fiddle according to your condition...see it http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleJS/ADukg/15831/

Comment: buddy try to understand your fiddle is great.But to get date `date.get('date')` is not working for me.`date.get('date')` this only returns the date in my code. if I add `date.getDate()` then it throws `date.getDate() is not a function`.If I add `date.get('date')` background is not working :-( :-(seriously I tried alot But I couldn't solve it:-(

Comment: okay do one thing.....create a fiddle for me with your controller code and template code and i will see from there where's the problem.

Comment: and more thing......why are you using `date.get('date')` instead of `date.getDate()` ?

Comment: was your calendar opening on clicking on grids. bcoz it is not opening in the fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158581/discussion-between-krish-and-lakshay).

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert date into date object hope it works

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    dateObj =new Date(date);
    console.log(date.getDate());
}
```