# Date.getTime not a function in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I'm running a node shell on the terminal. Here is the output:

```
> new Date("2018-06-03T02:49:50.307Z");
2018-06-03T02:49:50.307Z
> Date("2018-06-03T02:49:50.307Z").getTime();
TypeError: Date(...).getTime is not a function
> var d = Date("2018-06-03T02:49:50.307Z");
undefined
> d
'Wed Sep 19 2018 11:17:07 GMT-0400 (EDT)'
> d.getTime();
TypeError: d.getTime is not a function
> d.getTime;
undefined
> d.getDate();
TypeError: d.getDate is not a function
> d
'Wed Sep 19 2018 11:17:07 GMT-0400 (EDT)'
>
```

As you can see, both getDate and getTime are not functions of the Date object. But [other  Stackoverflow Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194546/date-gettime-is-not-a-function) seem to imply that they should be, and doing a CTRL+F on [the javascript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) reveals that this function is expected to exist.

The format for this time is the way Azure databases store datetimes. It looks like the Date object recognizes the format, since printing d returns a date.

Comment: `Date`, called as a function (rather than as a constructor), returns a string, not a `Date`.

Comment: It would be nice whoever marked this as a duplicate linked to the question so I could find the answer.

Comment: @jaredad7 There's a link to the duplicate question on top of your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the `new`. So `new Date("2018-06-03T02:49:50.307Z").getTime();` etc